# Canvas/Javascript periodic slow downs only at beginning

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've been having trouble using the canvas element and can't seem to locate the problem.

The slowdown happens every 5-15 seconds when the page is initially loaded. But, after tabbing over to facebook for a while and chatting with friends, it miraculousy stopped exhibiting slow downs.

My friends also see the periodic slowdowns and they use chrome/firefox

I have no idea what's happening!  I'm reading up on memory leaks/heap profiling, but I'm having a hard time locating the problem.

I initially only had one ball bouncing around, but I decided to put in 1000 balls to try and test performance, sorry :P

***EDIT1:*** Ok, I tried running the same code on Firefox(i've been using chrome) and the balls are moving significantly slower on firefox minus the horrible stutter I've been seeing on chrome... What's causing the browsers to use different speeds for the balls?

**WARNING WARNING EPILEPSY WARNING** [Link to live demo](http://sunwooz.xp3.biz/)

[Here's the code](https://github.com/sunwooz/jspong)

Comment: it is making my Lappy to go mad!

Comment: you are executing more than 3000 loops and still hopes that it will PC friendly?

Comment: Maybe my desktop is too powerful, because I'm not seeing any slow downs at all. I would suggest running the code through your favorite debugger's profiler as a first step.

Comment: @AspiringAqib: Where do you see 3000 loops?

Comment: hey @bergi 1000 at this `spawnObjects() for (i=1; i<1000;i++) {` and 1000 at this `update() for (i=0; i<balls.length;i++) {` and 1000 at this `render() for(i=0;i<balls.length;i++) {`

Comment: @AspiringAqib: Those are 3 loops with 1000 iterations each - should be no problem for any decent browser

Comment: Browser also uses memory buddy :D my 2 GB RAM laptop slows down while running the document created by the questioner :P I know 2 GB is normal memory range. Here browser is not issue, it is problem of CPU usage and RAM usage. You also see the @GeorgeP comment.

Comment: Ok... this is very strange.  I tried opening this on firefox(after using chrome) and the balls are moving significantly slower- minus the stutter I see on chrome.

Comment: chrome is light browser maybe it is good at doing calculations! I am also using chrome but the green balls don;t even move on it hahaha :P

Comment: I hate how it's so hard to get html5 stuff working the same on all browsers.  How does impactjs and other html5 engines get everything so uniform? hmmm

Comment: Luckily Pong only required one ball at a time!

Comment: try using several canvases and place them on top of each other.

Comment: it's interesting that you say that, because someone else previously told me not to use multiple canvases since it'll slow down performance.  How do you think doing that will solve this problem?

Comment: it won't help in your case I think, sorry, because you donot have any graphics that is static that you redraw on each iteration. another idea: cache the circle into an image and draw from the cache this way you won't need to calculate the circle every time. also, try to update and draw balls in the same loop.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using request animation frame it will try to hit 60 fps, and if it can't then it will settle for 30 fps, until it can deliver 60 fps. So the slowdown is your canvas running at 30 fps, and the jump to 60 fps makes things seem to speed up.

The reason why you're only hitting 30 fps in the beginning can be varied. In my case my computer is plenty powerful but I've got multiple monitors and I just opened the example in a new window on a new monitor, I suspect my OS limits only 1 monitor at a time to 60 fps unless I'm full screened in a game that takes up all 3 monitors. But this is not your problem, I just use it as an example as to why you need to be profiling and running performance tests yourself on a variety of setups, because there are any number of things that can be causing performance problems.

One of the reasons you get a perceived "slow down" and "speed up" is because you're updating positions on a frame by frame basis, but the time in between frames varies from 33ms to 16ms depending on what the current frame rate is. It would be advisable to make all of your update functions use the delta time (or the elapsed time since the previous frame) as a measure of how much to update the positions.

What you have:

```
Ball.prototype.update = function() {
  this.x += this.velocity.x;
  this.y += this.velocity.y;
}
```

We want to include a delta time in here

```
Ball.prototype.update = function(deltaTime) {
  this.x += this.velocity.x * deltaTime;
  this.y += this.velocity.y * deltaTime;
}
```

The only difference here will be that you're going to have to express your velocity in relation to time. For example, your velocity will be expressed as 100 pixels per second, and your delta Time will be expressed in seconds as well (with a value of around .016 or .033)

This won't fix the 30 fps but it will make your balls move at a consistent speed. When you first load the page, the browser needs to load all the other scripts you're including, parse and evaluate them, and in some cases will fire off some Garbage Collection (as is the case with the included jQuery). If you don't need jQuery or other such additional files you can avoid including them.

More importantly, you don't have to start rendering full speed ahead as soon as the page loads. In the case of games, they'll have their own loading screens and title screens preceding actual game rendering that players won't be able to tell the difference between 30 fps and 60 fps on anyway.